# Docusign Text Tabs in template not populating

Tags: node.js, typescript, docusignapi

I am using docusign (production account) to allow users to sign documents. I am trying to add data to textTabs that I create through the docusign dashboard. So say if I add a text box and call it nbShares, the below code does not populate the box. All the boxes I add in the dashboard such as signature, text, checkboxes etc are not shown in the generated link. I get no API errors either. I also tried to create customFields, and pass data to them as textTab - however this did not work either.

I think I may misunderstand the flow, I add all recipients and signers programatically - is that why I cant see the placeholders/buttons I add? I have also allowed collaboration in the fields I add, made them mandatory - yet they still do not appear.

Would really appreciate some help on this. This is my envelope definition - Im using the node sdk along with ts types.

```
const makeEnvelopeDefinition = async (
  templateName: string,
  user: User,
  dealId?: string,
): Promise<EnvelopeDefinition> => {
  const personToSign: Signer = {
    email: user.email,
    name: user.name,
    roleName: 'Signer',
    // Should this work?
    tabs: {
      textTabs: [
        { tabLabel: 'nbShares', value: '1000' },
      ],
    },
    clientUserId: DOCUSIGN_CLIENT_USER_ID,
    recipientId: '1',
  }
  const compositeTemplate: CompositeTemplate = {
    serverTemplates: [
      { sequence: '1', templateId: 'remote-template-id' },
    ],
    inlineTemplates: [
      {
        sequence: '1',
        recipients: {
          signers: [personToSign],
          certifiedDeliveries: [
            {
              email: 'someemail@something.com',
              recipientId: '77',
              name: 'Receipt of transaction',
            },
            {
              email: user.email,
              recipientId: '771',
              name: user.name,
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    ],
  }
  // create the envelope definition
  const envelope: EnvelopeDefinition = {
    emailSubject: 'Review signed document',
    status: 'sent',
    compositeTemplates: [compositeTemplate],
  }
  return envelope
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me the solution was changing my signer to this

```
const personToSign: Signer = {
    email: user.email,
    name: user.name,
    clientUserId: await getDocusignConfig().DOCUSIGN_CLIENT_USER_ID,
    recipientId: '1',
    routingOrder: '1', // Was missing this
    roleName: 'Signer', // Must match signer specified on docusign dashboard
    tabs: {
      textTabs: [
        {
          xPosition: '150',
          yPosition: '200',
          name: 'First Name',
          tabLabel: 'name', // Must match the dataLabel name specified on docusign
          value: 'Test',
        },
      ],
    },
  }
```

And enabling this setting 'When an envelope is sent, write the initial value of the field for all recipients' in 'Signing Settings' on docusign.